# Using an AD-integrated Enterprise CA to issue an Exchange 2010 certificate

Tags: exchange-2010, certificate-authority, ad-certificate-services

I have a small test network that includes Win2k8 R2 machines, an Enterprise CA server and an Exchange 2010 SP1 RU1 CAS server. I would like to issue a certificate for Exchange from the CA.

As the first step, I created the certificate request, which (according to OpenSSL) contains the following info:

```
C:\OpenSSL\bin>openssl req -in e.req -noout -text
Certificate Request:
    Data:
        Version: 0 (0x0)
        Subject: CN=mail.mnet.com, OU=IT, O=MNet, L=Budapest, ST=Budapest, C=HU
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
            RSA Public Key: (2048 bit)
                ...snip...
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        Attributes:
            1.3.6.1.4.1.311.13.2.3   :6.1.7600.2
            1.3.6.1.4.1.311.21.20    :unable to print attribute
            1.3.6.1.4.1.311.13.2.2   :unable to print attribute
        Requested Extensions:
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Digital Signature, Key Encipherment
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:
                DNS:cas.int.mnet.com, DNS:mail.mnet.com, DNS:autodiscover.mnet.com, DNS:pop.int.mnet.com, DNS:imap.int.mnet.com
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:FALSE
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier:
                F0:7E:53:47:BE:04:0F:5C:78:FD:63:8C:D6:5C:BC:0D:45:A3:4F:48
    Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
        ...snip...
```

As the second step, I would like to submit this request to the CA, but I get the following message:

```
The request contains no certificate information.

Denied by Policy Module 0x80094801, The request does not contain a certificate template extension of the CertificateTemplate request attribute.
```

What would be the best way to get this working?

How should I generate the same request from Exchange to include the info on which certificate to use?

How should I convince the CA to issue the certificate, even if the request doesn't match a certificate template?

(I'm actually interested in the answer to all three questions to learn more about both Exchange and the CA services.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Please* use the wizard that Exchange 2010 so helpfully provides for you - it's much easier.

It's in the Exchange Management Console under **Server Configuration**. In the Action Pane, choose the *New Exchange Certificate* wizard.

Fill in the required info, submit the generated file to your Enterprise CA using the **Web Server** template, then import the generated certificate back into Exchange using the wizard.

You might find [this video](http://www.msexchange.org/articles_tutorials/videos/exchange-server-2010/video-certificate-wizard-Exchange-2010.html) helpful.

Comment: How can I "submit the generated file to your Enterprise CA using the Web Server template"? I mean, I can submit the reqest to the CA, but how can I assign the template to it?

Comment: Your Enterprise CA usually has a web interface accessed via `http://<CA Server Name>/certsrv` - from there you can request a certificate. If you watch through the video I linked, it shows you the options you need to choose (including the Web Server template).

Comment: Thanks. For some reason I don't always have the option "Submit a certificate request by using a base-64-encoded CMC or PKCS #10 file, or submit a renewal request by using a base-64-encoded PKCS #7 file." in the Advanced Certificate Reqest tab. I might be missing some access rights.

Comment: How do you do this in Exchange 2007? I don't think it has that wizard.